# Node Insertion,Linked Lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have this code through which it inserts node at the starting.This code also contains a function which prints linked list and if empty it prints *linked list is empty* .

when i run this code , i have my ouput as *Linked list is empty* .

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
}* start = NULL;

void append(node* linkedlist, int data)
{
    node* new_element = NULL;
    new_element = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_element->data = data;
    if (linkedlist == NULL) {
        linkedlist = new_element;
        new_element->next = NULL;
    }

    else {
        new_element->next = (linkedlist)->next;
        (linkedlist)->next = new_element;
    }
}

int main()
{
    append(start, 4);
    append(start, 5);
    printList(start);
}
```

Update:

```
void printList(node* linkedlist)
{
    node* ptr = linkedlist;
    if (linkedlist == NULL) {
        printf("Linked list is empty");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {

        while (ptr != NULL) {
            cout << ptr->data;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

What could i be possibly doing wrong? What should i change in order to make it work?

Comment: And don't use a C++ compiler to compile C.

Comment: @nobar: the line  `void append(node *linkedlist, int data){` would fail to compile in C, since `node` is not a type (there is no typedef). This is just one of the differences between C and (a subset of) C++

Comment: @KostasRim i upvoted it for the time being, i have done this method before, i didn't know about the value being passed as copy , hence the upvote.Plus, i will hang on to a little bit more to see some more answers :)

Comment: @Downvoter, care to answer?

Comment: Because the program in your question is not C. Did you try to compile it? Why not?

Comment: @BOTJr. do not worry, its a very common error !

Comment: Funny.  The OP originally tagged this as C++, but someone else decided (incorrectly) that it wasn't and changed the tag.

Comment: @nobar, it was cpp but just to avoid the further explanation, i let him edit my post to c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here `linkedlist = new_element;` When passing arguments to a function they are passed by value. Even when you pass a `pointer` you are actually passing a copy of that pointer(you can verify by printing the address of `linkedlist` inside the function and outside the function). The statement `linkedlist = new_element;` assigns the `new_element` to a copy. Once the function return you end up with nothing (and a memory leak). Remember when you need to change a pointer itself you must use a double `pointer **`

Comment: or if OP does not want to your `pointer **` they can just return the new linked list: `node* append(node *linkedlist,int data){...`

Comment: Or pass by reference `void append(node*& linkedlist,int data)`

Comment: @NathanOliver He used `malloc()` and I made an assumption that he misplaced the c++ tag. Anyway, I made an edit, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @KostasRim No you were right.  I did not see the C tag was removed and still thought this was a C++ question.

Answer (score 2):

You put in the value of `start` which points to null. Then you copy it to another pointer `linkedlist` and set it to a new value. After the function `start` is still pointing to null though because you never changed the value of `start`.

You could try to change your declaration to

```
void append(node *&linkedlist,int data)
```

If you are using a c++ compiler.

else

```
void append(node **linkedlist,int data)
...
append(&start,4);
```

if you are using C

Answer (score 2):

For starters the code you showed is not valid C code. You are using C++ elements. So the program will not even compile as a C program.

As the node `start` that is initially set to `NULL` can be changed by the function you have to pass it by reference. Otherwise the function parameter `linkedlist` is a local variable of the function that will be changed in the function and at last will be destroyed after exiting the function. So the original pointer `start` itself will not be changed.

Also this else code block

```
    else {
        new_element->next = (linkedlist)->next;
        (linkedlist)->next = new_element;
    }
```

is wrong. This code block does not insert a new node in the beginning of the list. It inserts a new node after the first already existent node.

Take into account that the function name `append` is not suitable for inserting a node in the beginning of the list. It would be better to name it like `insert`.
The function can look the following way

```
int insert( struct node **linkedlist, int data )
{
    struct node *new_element = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_element != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_element->data = data;
        new_element->next = *linkedlist;
        *linkedlist = new_element;
    }

    return success;
}
```

If you indeed need a function that appends nodes to the list then it can look the following way

```
int append( struct node **linkedlist, int data )
{
    struct node *new_element = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_element != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_element->data = data;
        new_element->next = NULL;

        while ( *linkedlist != NULL ) linkedlist = &( *linkedlist )->next; 
        *linkedlist = new_element;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} *start = NULL;

int insert( struct node **linkedlist, int data )
{
    struct node *new_element = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_element != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_element->data = data;
        new_element->next = *linkedlist;
        *linkedlist = new_element;
    }

    return success;
}

int append( struct node **linkedlist, int data )
{
    struct node *new_element = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_element != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_element->data = data;
        new_element->next = NULL;

        while ( *linkedlist != NULL ) linkedlist = &( *linkedlist )->next; 
        *linkedlist = new_element;
    }

    return success;
}

void printList( struct node* linkedlist )
{
    if ( linkedlist == NULL ) 
    {
        puts( "Linked list is empty" );
    }
    else 
    {
        for ( struct node *current = linkedlist; current != NULL; current = current->next ) 
        {
            printf( "%d ", current->data );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) append( &start, i );
        else insert( &start, i );
    }

    printList( start );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
9 7 5 3 1 2 4 6 8 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In the append function you should

1. First initialise next of newnode to  be null
2. Check before inserting for empty list, if empty then then make this as head.
3. If it is not empty then make the new node point to the head of your list and make it the new head.
4. To reflect back the insertion done in append you should return the modified head from the function(Also modify main accordingly).

Look at this code:-

```
    node *append(node *linkedlist,int data){
        node *new_element=NULL;
        new_element=(node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_element->data=data;
        new_element->next=NULL;// initialise next of newnode to  be null here
        // In case of empty list make this as first node
        if(linkedlist==NULL)
        {
              linkedlist=new_element;
        }
       else
        {
            new_element->next=(linkedlist);//point the new node to head of list
            (linkedlist)=new_element;// make new node as head
        }
        return linkedlist;
    }


    int main()
    {
        start = append(start, 4);
        start = append(start, 5);
        printList(start);
    }
```

Comment: This has the same issue as the OP

Comment: Sorry about that, Handled it now

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your if statement is correct. I would do it like this

```
if(linkedlist == null)
{
    //head node is null i.e, linked list is empty hence make the new node as head node
    linkedlist = new_element;  
}else{
    //make the new node point to the head
    new_element->next = linkedlist;
    //make the new node as head node
    linkedlist = new_element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a parameter in C, it creates a local copy for the function to use.  When you modify the parameter inside the function, it only changes the local copy.

```
void f1( int a )
{
    a = 1; // modification does not affect the calling function
}

int b=0;
f1( b );
assert( b == 0 ); // b was not changed by f
```

In C (or C-style C++), if you want a function to modify a parameter, you need to pass it as a pointer:

```
void f2( int * a )
{
    (*a) = 1;
}

int b=0;
f2( &b );
assert( b == 1 ); // b was changed by f
```

If that parameter was already a pointer type, then you need to pass it as a pointer to a pointer:

```
void f3( int * * a )
{
    (*a) = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    (**a) = 1;
}

int * b = NULL;
f3( &b );
assert( b != NULL ); // the pointer was initialized
assert( *b == 1 ); // the pointed-to value was initialized
```

The assignment process can be a bit simpler in C++ because you can use [reference parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) instead of explicitly specifying the pointer.

Comment: Both approaches work in C++, which is more or less a superset of C.